# Where to install Windows on a laptop which has both a regular SSD and an M.2 SSD?

Tags: ssd, windows-8.1, thinkpad

I have a 16GB M.2 SSD in my T440p (Lenovo, it shipped with it) and just replaced the normal hard drive with a Samsung 840 Pro 256GB. When installing Windows 8.1 from scratch, where should I put it? Are there speed differences between those SSDs? Is there any way to determine the best setup? Also, does it improve the speed to install to one SSD and put the swap file on the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put it on your 256GB SSD, as minimum install size for Windows 8.1 is 16GB for 32bit version and 20GB for 64bit version.

Comment: thanks! does it make sense to put the swap file or something else on the small ssd (speedwise)?

Comment: the read and write (especially) performance on the Samsung 840 Pro outshines the M2, so there's no reason at all to put the swap file on the M2.